# vba or vsto or .. outlook development

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto

**Background:**

I have come up with an idea that will make things easier for the company I work for. They even seem excited about the idea. The idea is to make an addin for Outlook to help with a task. So after doing a bit of research (obviously, not enough). I downloaded a trial copy of VS2010 pro and created a VSTO addin.

After creating the addin, it was time to package it for a small test deployment. That's when I found out that this is a much more difficult thing to do. It seems MS does not ship Office 2010 with the runtime needed to run VSTO, so i'd have to package that as well. In a company environment, this is not something simple to do.

So, I might have to go back to the drawing board.

**Meat of the question:**

I've never created an addin for office before, I really want more of a "drop in" solution. I'm not sure if VBA is the right solution. It seems more of a "document" level application (or macro?). Does any one know what would be the best type of solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook API is not native .NET framework. To interact it with, .NET relies on marshaling and interrop assembly thus making it much more prone to errors and unstable.

From what I've seen so far with my outlook API experience, I would stick with VBA and you should consider retrieving a third party library that exposes outlook extended MAPI if you run in to much of trouble.

Comment: Hmm, I guess my main question is: what would the deployment method be like for VBA. I've tried understanding MS documentation, but something things seem to be outdated or just not relevant. Like, I've seen making a dll or is that for vbe...  is vbe the same as vba? They don't make this easy.

Answer (score 0):

NetOffice is pretty good - it is a set of managed .NET libraries that handles the COM API with Office and only needs XCopy installation.

The best part is it tracks all runtime callable wrappers ('RCWs') you create when accessing objects through COM and automatically releases them when you dispose the top-level object (the Application in most cases), so you won't get the issue of an orphaned COM 'handle' preventing you from closing Office.

Alternatively, the Office Primary Interop Assemblies should be on any computer that has the relevant version of Office installed (at least for >= Office 2007). But there are cases when it won't so you will have to cover that possibility. VSTO redistributable should already be installed on any computer with Office 2010 or 2013. For Office 2007 you will need to install it. But again, better safe than sorry so you should include it in your installer in both cases.

For details on deployment options look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx

As for VBA, I don't have experience for Outlook addins so I leave that to others to explain. Other VBA Office app addins (Excel/Word/Visio/PPT at least - not sure about the others as I haven't used them) can be installed either using registry keys or through XCopying the addin to a trusted location and then telling the user to open Options/Manage addins and tick the tick box.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Add-in Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/). They have tools that go beyond what Microsoft provides via Visual Studio.

[Their features for Outlook development](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/programming-outlook.php) greatly reduce the amount of effort required to build Outlook add-ins

Comment: So, the problem is deployment. I'm trying to get away from installation of other stuff (runtimes ect..). I've already created the add-in using VSTO. It's not much. Just parsing data into into the calendar. But the problem becomes that the deployment is hard because the IT manager will have to not only approve my add-in, but the additional crud it drags with it. Corporate IT departments don't like introducing new things into their unstable environment.

Comment: That is indeed a problem. If the IT Departments are locking it down, can you work with the business users? If there is significant demand for your add-in, it can put pressure on IT to support it.